CollectionView in .NET MAUI is not displaying items returned from an API call
I have an existing app that I need to upgrade to MAUI, having a slight issue on the display end. I have migrated up to .NET MAUI just recently and I know that I am close to getting these suckers displaying, though I am having a slight issue, I just don't know where exactly.
My API call returns the data as expected from the database, though the items in my ObservableCollection are not being displayed in the app when debugging.
This is my XAML markup:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SaleBeaconMobile.Views.MainPageCus"
             Title="Sale Alerts"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:SaleBeaconMobile.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:MainPageCusViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Debug" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_3" Order="Secondary" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"  Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Support" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_1"  Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Log Out" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_2"  Order="Secondary"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RefreshView>
            <CollectionView x:Name="CVSaleAlerts"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                    RemainingItemsThreshold="4"
                    RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
                    HeightRequest="300">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="280" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding bg}"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           WidthRequest="350"
                           HeightRequest="280"
                           MinimumHeightRequest="280"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

This is my view model:
using SaleBeaconMobile.Models;
using SaleBeaconMobile.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml;

namespace SaleBeaconMobile.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageCusViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly DataService _dataService = new DataService();
        private const int PageSize = 10;
        private int _currentPage = 0; // Track the current page for loading more data

        public ObservableCollection<Sale> Items { get; }

        private bool _isRefreshing;
        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get => _isRefreshing;
            set
            {
                _isRefreshing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand LoadMoreItemsCommand { get; }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await DownloadDataAsync());

        public MainPageCusViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Sale>();

            // Assign the command to LoadMoreItemsCommand
            LoadMoreItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadMoreItemsAsync());

            // Trigger initial data load
            Task.Run(async () => await DownloadDataAsync());
        }

        // Method to load initial data
        public async Task DownloadDataAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                IsRefreshing = true;

                // Fetch initial data (page 0 or starting page)
                var items = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync(0, PageSize);

                // Clear existing items and add new items
                Items.Clear();

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }

                // Update the current page
                _currentPage = 1; // Assuming pages start from 0
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions as needed
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }

        // Method to load more items for pagination or infinite scrolling
        public async Task LoadMoreItemsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsRefreshing)
                    return; // Prevent re-entry

                IsRefreshing = true;

                // Fetch more data based on the current page
                var items = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync(_currentPage, PageSize);

                // Add new items to the existing collection
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }

                // Increment the current page for the next load
                _currentPage++;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions as needed
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

I know that I am pretty close as the data is being retrieved properly, the idea is to bring back 10 records at a time from my API call, all of that works in postman as well in my older app. I am just unsure on the display end currently, not sure if it is an attribute I am missing or what. I was using a ListView with a collection prior to this and that all works but I think that I should be upgrading it all to .MAUI with the new attributes and features that comes along with that. I am not receiving any errors currently.
Thanks for any pointers and help! Cheers, Joe :)

I can't see any issue except that Task.Run(async .. what if you remove it and test again without Task.Run

if you hardcode test data instead of using the API call, does it work?

Thanks gents!  I will try it again and get back to you!  Cheers :)

Hi there. Small update here.  I switched out the image with a label and was able to see the image urls as labels, just not images.   I also hardcoded 3 Sale objects with three images that work in my Listview version and they do not show at all.  Possible I have left out some attribute on the xaml page? Not sure.

Another short update, I copied over some of the images to my resources/images folder and hard coded three records again and they show up no issue.  Could there be a remote image attribute I am missing or something like that? Cheers, joey

Last update on this topic, turns out I had to reinstall my SSL cert on the server and change my constants back to https:   it didn't like http urls it seems, thanks for your help!

Okay, thanks again for all of your suggestions, the images are all being displayed finally which is great I am experiencing a slight issue with the count/pagination, I will post my updated code in a new question so as to not confuse the topics. Cheers all!

Congrats and thanks for your update. Could you please share it as an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)

Okay :)  I had to wait to put up my latest code, I wanted to add in the refreshview to the collectionview code and test it out.  It seems to be working very nicely.  I will post my code below.

So my original issue to resolve was to move from Xamarin to .net 8.0 Maui mobile.   My old solution worked okay, I had a listview etc but it sucked really, things took way too long to load.  My new goal was to update up to .net 8.0 and to have my new CollectionView to function a lot better that the ListView.  It now does.   My app loads within 1 second if not faster, my server sits in Vancouver, BC and I am testing my app now from South Carolina where my biz partner lives and here in Halifax, Nova Scotia where I live. Though I am still working with a dev virtual server (tip: if you are working with a virtual server during your dev, you might think about creating a scheduled task to keep your API alive...just until you move it up to a 'live' server just so you have some sort of a 'reliable' API that is always waiting for your calls.)  The last issue I had was trying to  implement the refreshview around the collectionview, I did not get it working until today.  Not until I moved the layoutbounds up from the collectionview up to the refreshview tag!!!  I knew I was close :)  Here is my code for anyone who is struggling the same way I did.  Please feel free to use this! I still have some tidying up and error handling code wise in some places but man oh man, I am happy finally with this version. I thank all who helped me with suggestions and ideas throughout this process, truly. Sorry it took so long, but I wanted to get it correct before posting it all.  Please be well :)
My updated XAML code:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="yournamespace.Views.MainPageCus"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:yournamespace.ViewModels"
             xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:yournamespace.Models" 
             Title="Your Website/app name.com, etc">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:MainPageCusViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems x:Uid="tbOne" >
        <ToolbarItem Text="Debug" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_3" Order="Secondary" x:Name="tbDebug"  />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Settings" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked" Order="Secondary" x:Name="tbSettings"  />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Support" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_1" Order="Secondary" x:Name="tbSupport"  />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Buy us a Beer!" Order="Secondary" Clicked="ToolbarItem4_Clicked" x:Name="tbBeer"  />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Log Out" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_2" Order="Secondary" x:Name="tbLogOut"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <AbsoluteLayout>

          

            <Image IsVisible="{Binding ShowLabels}" Source="splashmaster.png"    
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, AutoSize, AutoSize" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>

            <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
             Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

                <!-- CollectionView -->
                <CollectionView x:Name="CVSaleAlerts"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                        ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="10"
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadMoreItemsCommand}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionChanged="CVSaleAlerts_SelectionChanged"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:Sale">
                            <Grid Padding="2" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding bg}"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               WidthRequest="350"
                               HeightRequest="280"
                               MinimumHeightRequest="280"
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </RefreshView>

            

        </AbsoluteLayout>
            
           

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>



My Code Behind Code:


using yournamespace.ViewModels;
using yournamespace.Models;

namespace yournamespace.Views;

public partial class MainPageCus : ContentPage
{
    MainPageCusViewModel viewModel;
    string debugtoggle = string.Empty;
    bool debug = false;

    public MainPageCus()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new MainPageCusViewModel();

 
    }


    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        try
        {
            
            string? accesstoken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("accesstoken");
            if (accesstoken == null)
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
            }

            
            string? accesstokenexpdate = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("accesstokenexpirydate");
            if (accesstokenexpdate == "" || accesstokenexpdate == null)
            {
                if (DateTime.Parse(accesstokenexpdate.ToString()) < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }


    //settings page
    private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Settings());
    }

    //support page
    private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Support());
    }

    //buyusabeer page
    private async void ToolbarItem3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new BuyUsABeer());
    }

    //logout
    private  void ToolbarItem_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Clear the navigation stack
            //Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new LoginPage(), Navigation.NavigationStack[0]);
            //await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();

           

            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR!!!:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    //debug
    private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Debug());
    }

    //beer page
    private async void ToolbarItem4_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new BuyUsABeer());
    }

    private async void CVSaleAlerts_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure we have a valid selected item
        var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Sale;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        // Check if the item has a URL and handle accordingly
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.adurl))
        {
            // Open the ad URL in the system's default browser
            await Browser.OpenAsync(item.adurl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }
        else
        {
            // Navigate to the detailed sales page if no ad URL is present
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new CU_Sales_Active_Details(new CU_Sale_Active_Details_ViewModel(item)));
        }

        // Send click data to the server or database
        if (BindingContext is MainPageCusViewModel viewModel)
        {
            await viewModel.SendClickData(item);
        }

        // Optionally, deselect the item after processing
        //((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }

    private void OnRefreshButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your refresh logic here, such as triggering the ViewModel command
        var viewModel = BindingContext as MainPageCusViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }



}




My ViewModel Code:

using yournamespace.Models;
using yournamespace.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml;

namespace yournamespace.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageCusViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly DataService _dataService = new DataService();
        private const int PageSize = 10;
        private int _currentPage = 0; // Track the current page for loading more data
        private bool _isLoadingMore = false;
        public ObservableCollection<Sale> Items { get; }

        private bool isRefreshing;
        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get => isRefreshing;
            set => SetProperty(ref isRefreshing, value);
        }

        private bool isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => isBusy;
            set => SetProperty(ref isBusy, value);
        }



        private bool _Debug;
        public bool Debug
        {
            get => _Debug;
            set
            {
                _Debug = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _ShowLabels;
        public bool ShowLabels
        {
            get => _ShowLabels;
            set
            {
                _ShowLabels = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private int _totalPageCount = 0;
        public int TotalPageCount
        {
            get => _totalPageCount;
            set
            {
                _totalPageCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private string _Color = "#003366";
        public string Color
        {
            get => _Color;
            set
            {
                _Color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        private int _totalCount = 0;
        public int TotalCount
        {
            get => _totalCount;
            set
            {
                _totalCount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _currentCountSalesAds;
        public int CurrentCountSalesAds
        {
            get => _currentCountSalesAds;
            set
            {
                _currentCountSalesAds = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public ICommand LoadMoreItemsCommand => new Command(async () => await LoadMoreItemsAsync());

        public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await DownloadDataAsync());

        public MainPageCusViewModel()
        {

            Items = new ObservableCollection<Sale>();
            ShowLabels = true;
            // Trigger initial data load
            Task.Run(async () => await DownloadDataAsync());

        }

        // Method to load initial data
        public async Task DownloadDataAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                IsRefreshing = true;
                IsBusy = true; // Show the ActivityIndicator
                Color = "#ffffff";

                var items = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync(0, PageSize);

                if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
                {
                    Items.Clear();

                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        Items.Add(item);
                    }

                    TotalCount = items[0].totalcount; // Assuming first item's totalcount is representative
                    CurrentCountSalesAds = items.Count;
                    _currentPage = 1; // Reset to the first page after initial load
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions as needed
            }
            finally
            {
                IsRefreshing = false;
                IsBusy = false;
                ShowLabels = false;
            }
        }

        // Method to load more items for pagination or infinite scrolling
        public async Task LoadMoreItemsAsync()
        {
            // Check if loading is already in progress or if we have loaded all items
            if (_isLoadingMore || CurrentCountSalesAds >= TotalCount)
                return;

            _isLoadingMore = true;

            try
            {
                //IsRefreshing = true;
                IsBusy = true; // Show the ActivityIndicator

                // Fetch more data based on the current page
                var items = await _dataService.GetItemsAsync(_currentPage, PageSize);

                if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        Items.Add(item);
                    }

                    CurrentCountSalesAds += items.Count;
                    _currentPage++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions as needed
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                //IsRefreshing = false;
                _isLoadingMore = false;
            }
        }

        //send click data to db...
        public async Task SendClickData(Sale item)
        {
            await _dataService.SendClickData(item);
        }



    }
}

Cheers, Joe :)
